# How to Study this 4G Network Failure?

Tags: wireless-networking, modem, signal-strength, antenna

The mimo antenna is directed towards the 4G tower. 
I keep the signal strength at 75% because it reaches this way the best ping, download and upload rates. 
However, I am experiencing failures in endurance tests, please see the test file below. 
There is a direct ethernet connection from the modem to the Chromebook/... 
Error messages and failure points

- Chromebook: *36.7/227 GB, Failed - Unknown network error. From horatio.cs.nya.edu.*
- ...

Proposals for the solution to resume interrupted download

- *[Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en)* cannot resume interrupted download itself
- ...

### Proposals for Matija Nalis' answer

Expected number of tries needed to get 1/4 TB file is about 3-5, so I put there 10 in `--tries` as the upperbound.

- Number of attempts, random wait and time between failed retrievals

  ```
  # https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html
  wget --tries=10 --waitretry=15 --random-wait \
      http://horatio.cs.nyu.edu/mit/tiny/data/tiny_images.bin
  ```

  which passes my initial test reaching 4-6 MB/s; TODO endurance test
- ....

Test file: 227 GB file [here](http://horatio.cs.nyu.edu/mit/tiny/data/index.html)
Case in Google Productforums: [How to Resume Interrupted Download in Chrome by Chrome itself?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TPZsSgmyEPc;context-place=forum/chrome)
Enhancement in Ticket Tracker of Chrono Download Manager: [here](http://bugs.chronodownloader.net/view.php?id=1645) with ID 0001645

Router/modem: TP-Link MR200
Mimo antenna: [Fuj:tech 2G/3G/4G 2 x 5 m ‐duplex antenna](https://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/product/7183/ggdbq/Fuj-tech-2G-3G-4G-2-x-5-m-kaksoisantenni)
4G Signal Quality: strength: 75 % but ping/download/upload best
Profiling Application for the location of the tower: *[Network Cell Info Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilysis.cellinfolite&hl=en)*
System: Chromebook 2 Acer 13"

Comment: What "test" are you talking about?

Comment: @Dog Please, see the test file below. I use a bundle of files from different sources in testing the system.

Comment: You expect us to download a 227 GB test file? That is 22.7 times bigger than my monthly data allowance.

Comment: @DavidPostill Not necessary. There is many other files there too which you can use. It is more important to understand the case theoretically and how to deal with it. - - Again, downvoter, leave a feedback. I do not think this is too broad. This is very specific actually where a nice idea can solve the case fast.

Comment: How do you know this? "This is very specific actually where a nice idea can solve the case fast. "?

Comment: @Xavierjazz You just need to add one if clause and while loop in the download manager to fix the case. Other interest is how to do it with wget. By reading code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like 4G issue that connection gets dropped from time to time. You could try improving your signal, or test with different tower. Other than that, your tplink might be having problems, you may want to try different piece of equipment.

Orhogonal to that, you might use software that copes with such dropouts (like `wget`). Also implement some fast monitoring so you know when connection drops (like `smokeping`)

Comment: I've never used  *Chrono Download Manager* so can't comment on that - but if it works for you, great (I was under impression from your questuion it didn't work). `smokeping` won't be integrated with downloads, it will simply do `ping 8.8.8.8` or whatever and draw graphs so you can see your connection quality issues to better debug it.

Comment: @Masi you do not need to integrate it, it works standalone. `wget` has its own options to resume interrupted transfers, see its man and info pages.

Comment: @Masi I'm not near console right now to check, but for example search for `retries` on https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: @Masi your `wget` options looks just fine. `smokeping` **won't** help with wget speed at all. It can help you find root cause of your 4G connection breaking all the time (it shouldn't be doing that), when combined with moving to other tower, changing hardware etc as explained in the answer.

Comment: I cannot identify any other towers here near. There is only one. I am using the application *Network Cell Info Lite*.